# Rotate an icon when containing Button is clicked

Tags: javascript, material-ui, transition

I have a Material-UI button whose markup looks like this:

```
<Button
  disableFocusRipple={true}
  disableRipple={true}
  color="inherit"
  onClick={openBlogMenu}
  className={classes.blogButtonStyle}
>
  <LibraryBooksIcon />
  Blog
  {!blogMenu && <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
  {blogMenu && <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />}
</Button>
<BlogDropDown pageURL={pageURL} />
```

Here, the `openBlogMenu` changes the `blogMenu` Redux state which toggles `BlogDropDown` into view. As apparent, I'm also reading this state to toggle between the two arrow icons, `KeyboardArrowDownIcon` and `KeyboardArrowUpIcon`.

So far, this setup works smooth. However, I'm keen on doing away with `KeyboardArrowUpIcon` altogether and instead, making `KeyboardArrowDownIcon` rotate 180 degrees upon click.

I know it's as easy as just adding one of the available pseudo-classes, e.g., `:active` or `:focus` to the icon element. But then it'll only rotate if the icon itself is clicked rather than the entire button.

I also understand one could just dynamically add a `transform` attribute (`transform: rotate(180deg);`) to the icon's CSS in the click handler, but that wouldn't animate the transition.

Any tips?

**P.S.**: For illustration of what I'm looking for, check out menu option **More** on https://www.flipkart.com/

Comment: `<Button style={{ transform: [{ rotate: blogMenu ? '180deg' : '0deg' }] }} />` Tried this?

Comment: Won't this rotate the entire button instead of just the arrow icon? Also, this won't animate the transition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to only flip the icon, not the button. Here is the solution that works perfectly fine for me:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles (theme => ({
    open : {
         transform: "scaleX(1)",
    },
    close: {
         transform: "scaleX(-1)",
    },
}));

export default function Test() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const drawerToggle = () => { setOpen(!open) };
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <IconButton aria-label="open drawer" onClick={drawerToggle} edge="start">
            <MenuOpenRoundedIcon className={clsx(!open && classes.close, open && classes.open)}/>
        </IconButton>
    )
}
```

Use `clsx` (or any equivalent conditional class selector) to assign when the icon needs to be flipped based on the state of the button. Here, I'm using a state hook, `open`, and toggle its boolean value on click. Later, I used `clsx` to decide, based on the value of `open`, which class I assign to the **icon**, i.e., which direction I need to flip it.

If you want to flip vertically, you can use `scaleY` instead.

Here is the code I wrote in the code sandbox with both Button and IconButton examples (vertical and horizontal): https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-maxwell-3kcge?file=/src/App.js